# How can I update state twice in a Parent component from a Child component?

Tags: reactjs, axios, components, rendering, use-state

I pass an "isLoadingToggle" to my Child component like so:

```
export function Parent() {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

function toggleIsLoading() {
  setIsLoading(!isLoading)
}

return ( <Child toggleIsLoading={toggleIsLoading} /> )

}
```

and the Child:

```
export function Child({ toggleIsLoading }) {

...

const toggle = useCallback(() => {
   // set the isLoading effect in the parent
   toggleIsLoading()

   axios.post(someUrl...)
   .then(response =>
      // do something with response
      // then tell the parent it's not loading anymore
      toggleIsLoading()
   }).catch(error => {
      // do something with error
      // then tell the parent it's not loading anymore
      toggleIsLoading()
   })
 }, []);

return ( <Button onClick={toggle}>Toggle isLoading in parent!</Button> )
```

**Only the first isLoading state change is registered**. The second call, after the `axios` post, is not.

How can I get isLoading to toggle in the parent whenever I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky to explain what's happening here. anytime you mutate the state, the entire component re-renders. So when you get response and `toggleIsLoading()` is invoked. It doesn't really toggles the value of `isLoading`. It uses the old `isLoading` value from first render.

What you can do is pass the boolean param to `toggleIsLoading` like this

```
toggleIsLoading(true)
toggleIsLoading(false)
```

and define your function like this

```
function toggleIsLoading(loading) {
  setIsLoading(loading)
}
```

Here is working demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vgrkkf?file=src/Parent.js